# Assigning a python command to a mouse hotkey

Tags: python, shortcut

I am using an add-on called [hexblender](https://github.com/cmrglab/hexblender), which has some buttons that are useful for making meshes for finite-element models. I would like to assign one of the button's python commands to mouse button 4.

When I hover over the button, it says:

> Python: `bpy.ops.hexblender.adjust_nodes_linear()`

When I run the command from the command line, it does the right thing. Is there a way to assign this command to mouse button 4? I can assign other things to mouse button 4 but I cannot figure this out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

1. open *User Preferences* -> *Input*
2. open some category and click *Add New* button
3. insert `hexblender.adjust_nodes_linear` into the input field
4. assign some keyboard shortcut
5. test the keyboard shortcut and if it works, use the X-Mouse Button Control application to set your mouse button action to trigger your keyboard shortcut